# Get form control using string name VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have a control on a form `UserNameCtrl` and that control has a sub called `LoadCtrl`

I essentially have loads of these subs for clicks, so I want to put them all into one event handler

```
Private Sub NewsletterBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewsletterBtn.Click, NewsletterImage.Click
    If Not MainNewsletterCtrl.Loaded() Then MainNewsletterCtrl.Load()
End Sub
```

However within each of the subs the control names are hardcoded to call the `.loaded` and `.load` functionality.

I've wrote a new version of this

```
Private Sub GenericNavItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim ctrl As Control = Controls.Find(sender.tag, True).FirstOrDefault

       'Want to do the Controlname.Load here           

    End Sub
```

Using the tag (which I named as the control name) I got the corresponding control. But it's bringing back it as a control rather than of the type I want it to be.

I know I declare it as Control, but I don't know how I can cast it to be the `ControlName.Load` rather than the generic control.

Comment: Do these controls inherit from a base control or implement an interface that has the `Loaded()` and `Load()` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are all the same class (or base class), then just cast to that class. If they are all different class but have the same method Load and Loaded, then I suggest you create an interface.

```
Interface ISomeName

    Sub Load()
    Function Loaded() As Boolean()

End Interface
```

Make sure all your class implement it and then just cast to that interface.

```
Private Sub GenericNavItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctrl As Control = Controls.Find(sender.tag, True).FirstOrDefault
    Dim ctrlInterface As ISomeName = CType(ctrl, ISomeName)

    If Not ctrlInterface.Loaded() Then ctrlInterface.Load()

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is fantastic. I don't know why I didn't think of this before. Thank you, my code is much cleaner now. @the_lotus